# Разложение x^(1/3), бесконечное суммирование

Tags: c++, c, математика, ряды, численные-методы

Необходимо реализовать на языке Си бесконечное суммирование с заданной точностью по данной формуле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

точность вводится с клавиатуры. Чтобы ряд являлся сходящимся, x следует взять в диапазоне (0; 1).
Как вы могли заметить, данный ряд является разложением x^(1/3)
Я не могу придумать как находить k-ый элемент, так как не знаю, по какой закономерности изменяется числитель, сначала он умножается на 2, затем на 5, после на 8...

Comment: Поиск по метке [`ряды`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%8b?tab=Newest) покажет много интересных решений похожих задач...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот теперь вопрос стал нормальным, на который смело можно дать ответ.

Разложение в ряд в вашем вопросе имеет вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, бывает и такой биномиальный коэффициент, с дробным индексом :) И вот как он записывается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, собственно, и вся хитрость. Распишите с помощью этой формулы несколько первых коэффициентов, и станет понятнее.